# Woocommerce print notice is printing double

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On WooCommerce I have a hook being called that will show an error message if there are too many items of a certain tag in the cart.  The issue is that if I scroll down in the page and then hover over the cart it causes the notice to show up at the top and middle of the screen.  Any ideas?

im using this add action

add_action('woocommerce_mini_cart_contents', 'i9wtl_cart_hider_free');

and this is how i am calling the notice

```
wc_print_notice( $i9wtl_errorOutput, "error" );
```

[image: The error is the blue notice but its showing up twice but only happens when you scroll down in the page]

Comment: Ill try it out but not sure if itll help,  I found that its popping up with 2 messages because the original mini cart is behind the one that we can see on screen.  Is there an if statement i could run to have it not show a message on the phantom cart?

Comment: It's complicate to speak about virtually… In all projects that I have done or many others, I have never see this use for WooCommerce notices. So I can't know what will do if you add an if statement… Now the thing may be is that you should limit the container height enabling a vertical overflow (CSS). Also may be you should need to change of hook using `woocommerce_before_mini_cart` or `woocommerce_before_mini_cart_contents` action hooks instead.

Comment: Okay thank you so much one last question is there a hook that will fire each time a page is loaded?

Comment: basically if there are too many certain items in the cart itll post a message saying they need to remove some.

Comment: You have to try for example `template_redirect` adding some conditions like 
`! WC()->cart->is_empty()` and the some [woocommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) (to restrict it to necessary pages) + your code…